# Combinations in matrix on a per-row basis

Tags: python, combinations

(1) Given:

```py
matrix = [[1528.1, 1530.1, 1546.1, 1552.5, 1565.2], [1529.1, 1531.1, 1547.1, 1550.5, 1564.2]]
```

(2) Compute:

```py
print("combo[0]=", list(itertools.combinations(matrix[0], 3)))

print("combo[1]=", list(itertools.combinations(matrix[1], 3)))
```

(3) Results:

```py
combo[0]= [
(1528.1, 1530.1, 1546.1), (1528.1, 1530.1, 1552.5), (1528.1, 1530.1, 1565.2), (1528.1, 1546.1, 1552.5), 
(1528.1, 1546.1, 1565.2), (1528.1, 1552.5, 1565.2), (1530.1, 1546.1, 1552.5), (1530.1, 1546.1, 1565.2),
(1530.1, 1552.5, 1565.2), (1546.1, 1552.5, 1565.2)
]

combo[1]= [(1529.1, 1531.1, 1547.1), (1529.1, 1531.1, 1550.5), (1529.1, 1531.1, 1564.2), (1529.1, 1547.1, 1550.5), 
(1529.1, 1547.1, 1564.2), (1529.1, 1550.5, 1564.2), (1531.1, 1547.1, 1550.5), (1531.1, 1547.1, 1564.2), 
(1531.1, 1550.5, 1564.2), (1547.1, 1550.5, 1564.2)
]
```

Question: 
What is the most pythonic (and compact and/or efficient) format to achieve a resultant matrix 
`combo=[combo[0], combo[1]]`?

Comment: Basically, I would like to generate the resultant combo matrix whose ith row-vector equals to the combinations obtained from the ith-row in the original matrix. The main problem for me (I'm new to python) is that itertools.combinatin seems not to work on a 2D list; that's why I specified itertools.combinations(matrix(i),3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe:

```py
import itertools

matrix = [[1528.1, 1530.1, 1546.1, 1552.5, 1565.2], [1529.1, 1531.1, 1547.1, 1550.5, 1564.2]]

combo=list(map(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 3)), matrix))
```

Outputs:

```py
[[(1528.1, 1530.1, 1546.1), (1528.1, 1530.1, 1552.5), (1528.1, 1530.1, 1565.2), (1528.1, 1546.1, 1552.5), (1528.1, 1546.1, 1565.2), (1528.1, 1552.5, 1565.2), (1530.1, 1546.1, 1552.5), (1530.1, 1546.1, 1565.2), (1530.1, 1552.5, 1565.2), (1546.1, 1552.5, 1565.2)], [(1529.1, 1531.1, 1547.1), (1529.1, 1531.1, 1550.5), (1529.1, 1531.1, 1564.2), (1529.1, 1547.1, 1550.5), (1529.1, 1547.1, 1564.2), (1529.1, 1550.5, 1564.2), (1531.1, 1547.1, 1550.5), (1531.1, 1547.1, 1564.2), (1531.1, 1550.5, 1564.2), (1547.1, 1550.5, 1564.2)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code:

```
import itertools
matrix = [[1528.1, 1530.1, 1546.1, 1552.5, 1565.2], [1529.1, 1531.1, 1547.1, 1550.5, 1564.2]]
matrix_combo = [list(itertools.combinations(matrix[i],3)) for i in range(len(matrix))]
print(matrix_combo)
```

for in range loop:

```
import itertools
matrix = [[1528.1, 1530.1, 1546.1, 1552.5, 1565.2], [1529.1, 1531.1, 1547.1, 1550.5, 1564.2]]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix_combo = [list(itertools.combinations(matrix[i],3))]
print(matrix_combo)
```

Comment: This code certainly works as expected. I wonder if there is any alternative to the for in range loop.

Comment: @ajbg add for in range loop example